# Is there a way to avoid storing the AWS_SECRET_KEY on the .ebextensions?

Tags: security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm deploying a `Django based` project on `AWS Elastic Beanstalk`.

I have been following the `Amazon example`, where I add my credentials (`ACCESS_KEY/SECRET`) to my `app.config` under the `.ebextentions` directory.

The same config file has:

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

Problem is that this is forcing me to store my credentials under `Version Control`, and I will like to avoid that.

I tried to remove the credentials and then add them with `eb setenv`, but the problem is that the two `django commands` require the these settings to be set on the environment.

I'm using the `v3 cli`:

```
eb create -db -c foo bar --profile foobar
```

where `foobar` is the name of the profile under `~/.aws/credentials`, and where I want to keep my secret credentials.

What is the best security practices for the `AWS credentials` using `EB`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `.ebextensions` but better create specific IAM role for your purpose and use it. That's more secure than having admin privileges for any specific task. This way, you can also invalidate these credentials in case it's getting hacked and you're not exposing your AWS account as a whole.

Comment: Yes, by credentials, I mean an IAM role, but the IAM I need for Elastic Beanstalk is still very powerful and I need to protect.

Comment: what exactly is the issue with `eb setenv`? this is the way to do it.

Comment: Both the "migrate" and "collectstatic" commands require access to RDS and S3 respectively. The setenv seems to be executed AFTER the "container_commands", so the commands fail because of lack of access to AWS Infrastructure. One solution would be to remove those commands and execute them via an ssh command, but if you are forced to do stuff like that, then the value of EB begins to go down

Comment: are you sure about the precedence? environment variables are supposed to be setup with the box kickoff. go ahead and check your web console to check if the environment variables are really there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the collecstatic step from the config file, and simply take care of uploading statics on the build side.

After that, all credentials can be removed and all other boto commands will grab the credentials from the security role on the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to keep the AWS credentials, but create a policy that ONLY allows them to POST objects on the one bucket used for /static.